# Convert String to StaticString

Tags: swift, string

Is there a way in Swift 3.0 to get a `StaticString` type out of a `String` type which is complex?

Example (needs a conversion to work):

```
let aString: StaticString = "One part" + "Second part"
```

Comment: `let str: StaticString = "\(part1)\(part2)"` is this what you need

Comment: @InderKumarRathore Actually the result is the same "Cannot convert value of one type to another"

Comment: I read the documentation and it says `StaticString : A string type designed to represent text that is known at compile time.`

Comment: Because of above constraint I don't think you can have dynamic text in it

Comment: @MartinR just curious if there is any hack, some bit established 3rd party libraries with SWIFT 3 started to use this type where I would really expect some sort of dynamic behaviour.

Comment: The os_log API expects StaticString messages. It would be nice to be able to log dynamic messages.

Comment: @VolkerMohr You can use `os_log` with dynamic strings. It would be pretty useless if you couldn't.

Answer (score 13):

This is not possible, because a `StaticString` is defined as

> A simple string designed to represent text that is "knowable at
>   compile-time". ([Reference](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/type/StaticString/))

String concatenation happens at runtime.

I don't know what you are planing to do, but you can do something like that:

```
func aMethod(i: Int) -> StaticString {
    switch i {
    case 0:
        return "Simple"
    case 1:
        return "Complex"
    default:
        return "Default"
    }
}
let result = aMethod(i: 1)
print("\(type(of: result)): \(result)") // prints "StaticString: Complex"
```

Comment: Thank you Michael, but I am really interested in a generic hack way to do this sort of conversion.

Comment: "String concatenation happens at runtime." was key to satisfy my search (w/ an upvote, though i'd love a reference for it ;).

Answer (score 11):

You can use format specifiers like `%d` or `%s`
eg:

```
os_log("Successfully fetched %d recordings.", type: .info, count)
os_log("Getting recordings from %s.",
  type: .info, url.absoluteString)
```

for more info [check here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/605079-migrating-to-unified-logging-console-and-instruments)

Answer (score 5):

Depends on your actual use case, you may have some way to work it around. For example, if you are dealing with `os_log`, you can use `%@` if you want to use Swift `String` instead of `CVarArg`.

```
//os_log("Compiler error with: \(string).", log: log)
os_log("This is OK: %@.", log: log, string)
```